# Why the backgroundworker and progressBar are not working correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms

What i see is the progressBar get each time from the beginning moving to the right a bit then start over again nonstop.

What i wanted to do is that each time my program is waiting for the next update in this case 10 seconds the progressBar will mobf 10 steps(seconds) to the right when it's getting to the end make a new update.

This is what i did now:

In the constructor i changed and only make the backgroundworker to start. RunWorkerAsync()
Then in the bottom im using the 3 events of the backgroundworker:

```
private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);

                    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
                    page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
                    TextExtractor.ExtractDateTime(page, newText, dateTime);
                    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
                    w.Write(page);
                    w.Close();
                    TextExtractor.ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html", newText, dateTime);
                }
            }
        }

        private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label9.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;
            scrollLabel1.Reset();
            scrollLabel1.Text = " ";
            scrollLabel1.Invalidate();
            combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
            this.scrollLabel1.Text = combindedString;
            scrollLabel1.Invalidate();


        }

        private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                label10.Text = "Canceled!";
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                label10.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                label10.Text = "Done!";
            }
        }
```

I cut the update method to two some in the DoWork event and some in the progressChanged event.
The probelms are now:

How do i make the backgroundworker after 10 seconds or when its get to 100% to reset it all and start over again and again nonstop ?

Second when im running now the program the whole text and the progressBar is like stop/stuck for second or less each 10% of progress then continue untill 100% it dosent move smooth.

Comment: You're definitely using it wrong. The background work that you want to accomplish should be inside your `DoWork` handler (or methods it calls). It looks like the bulk of the work that you're doing is being performed by `Update` which you've called from inside your `ProgressChanged` handler - so rather than it happening in the background, you've forced it back into the UI thread.

Comment: You set back the Counter to 0. The Backgroundworker runs that fast, that you never see a Change. It is 10 - 0 - 10 - 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handful of things that are wrong with the way you're using `BackgroundWorker`.

- You're passing `temp` to the `DoWork` event, but then not using it. (It's in `e.Argument`, inside the `DoWork` event.)
- Your `DoWork` event is an infinite loop with no hope of ending. Your worker supports cancellation but you never check for it.
- Your `ProgressChanged` event is called rapidly - multiple times per second - too rapidly for you to see any changes in the UI because it doesn't even have time to refresh.

Since all of the work in your `BackgroundWorker` is running on the UI thread anyway, there may be a better way of doing what you're trying to achieve.

Try dropping a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control onto your form, set the interval to 10 seconds, and then call `Update()` from there.

- You can keep your `progressBar1` and update its value too.
- Everything in the `Timer.Tick` event already runs on the UI thread.
- It runs until you tell it to stop, which is what you're doing with the `while(true)` loop in `DoWork`.

Comment: Grant i tried to use a timer control before the backgroundworker the problem is in my Update method im downloading a content im invalidating the scrollbar and do more some other things there so each time the timer get to 10 the whole scrollbar with the text inside is stuck/hold for one second and then continue. The ScrollBar is a Label type class and the TextExtractor is another class where im extracting/parsing text from a website. I wanted to use a backgroundworker so the user will see it moving smooth the text each time its getting to 10 seconds and make update.

Comment: Grant updated my question now with what i did can you look please ? I have two problems now.